# Bootstrap 4 change accordion behaviour

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-accordion

I'm using HTML templates, which are based on Bootstrap 4.3.1 to present my students with learning content. In the current templates, all accordion panels are closed on page load and each accordion panel can be opened regardless of how many others have also been opened.

A working example can be found on this CodePen: https://codepen.io/hagelslag1001/pen/MWGeZJr

The HTML code is as follows:

```
<h2>Accordion: Group of 2</h2>
<p class="small">Accordion: start copy</p>
<!-- Accordion headings should be changed to respect page hierarchy -->
<div class="accordion shadow mb-5">
   <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
         <h2 class="card-title">
            Accordion 1 of 2
         </h2>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse">
         <div class="card-body">
            <p>Insert Accordion 1 of 2 content here.</p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header">
         <h2 class="card-title">
            Accordion 2 of 2
         </h2>
      </div>
      <div class="collapse">
         <div class="card-body">
            <p>Insert Accordion 2 of 2 content here.</p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<p class="small">Accordion: end copy</p>
```

Is it possible to change this default behaviour so that only one panel can be opened at a time? (i.e. as soon as a new panel is opened, the previously opened panel will automatically close)

The Bootstrap examples use (`data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne"`) to accomplish this for the accordions in these templates

I can't figure out how to accomplish this, since the HTML code for the accordions in these templates look different than the Bootstrap 4 examples, which use either an a or button tag to trigger the collapsible event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simpler answer based on your CodePen: https://codepen.io/mrtcntn/pen/MWGeZdP

[According the Bootstrap 4 docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#accordion-example), you need `id="accordion"` on the top level `div` and you don't need to give ids like `id="accordion_1"` and `id="accordion_2"`.

Therefore I removed the first portion from the JS and added `id="accordion"` at line 18 in the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by letting javascript check for active classes and only allowing one at the time. Here's a simplified example.

```js
// DOM here
let nav = document.querySelector(".nav");

// Handlers here
const clickHandler = function (e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains("nav__link")) {
    const link = e.target;
    const siblings = link.closest(".nav").querySelectorAll(".nav__link");

    link.classList.toggle("active");

    // removes all actives except for the clicked one
    siblings.forEach((el) => {
      if (el !== link) el.classList.remove("active");
    });
  }
};

// Listeners here
nav.addEventListener("click", clickHandler);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.nav__link {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.active {
  background: #0f0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="nav">
      <ul class="nav__links">
                <li class="nav__item">
                    <a class="nav__link" href="#accordeon--1">Accordeon 1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav__item">
                    <a class="nav__link" href="#accordeon--2">Accordeon 2</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav__item">
                    <a class="nav__link" href="#accordeon--3">Accordeon 3</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav__item">
                    <a class="nav__link" href="#accordeon--4"
                        >Accordeon 4</a
                    >
                </li>
            </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Dear @fuziion, thanks for your swift reply. I forgot to mention that I'm totally naive regarding js. I know a bit of HTML and CSS only. I guess your answer could help me on my way, but the way it's described right now looks like algebra to me. I can't fanthom how to apply the nav and nav-link to my situation. I'm a newbie, sorry. Still, thanks a lot for your effort.

Comment: Hi Hagelslag, you don't have to include the nav and nav-link to your code, its just for the example. the javascript listens for clicks, and whenever you click a accordeon it checks for the "active" class, which makes the text background green, or in your example the accordeon open, what you have to do is make the javascript listen for your accordeon active class, which is from what I've seen a class called `show` on the button that opens your accordeon. If you need more help just let me know, make sure to add this answer as solution if it helped.

Comment: As stated in Bootstrap 4 docs (here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#accordion-example) accordion feature already supports this feature with proper HTML tags, so I think it is not a good idea to alter how Bootstrap works.

Comment: Nice one! I don't work a crazy amount with bootstrap, so @Hagelslag Mert's answer is the thing you need!

Comment: I am not a pure JS guy either, but this solution also looks bulletproof at the second glance, i.e. it won't seem to break default Bootstrap functionality.

Comment: Yeah it will also function identical, but I do think that if there's a build in solution inside bootstrap its better to use it instead of custom coding a js script on top of it.